# Specify location for android api for AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Today, I decided to try Android Studio. When opening AVD Manager from the `Tools > Android > AVD Manager` menu on Android Studio, the list shows that the AVD named DroidBox fails because of "Unknown target android-16". I created that Virtual Device back when I used Eclipse for Android programming.

I have android-16 downloaded on my system (I know the path to the dir, and it has worked before), but apparently the location isn't being seen.

How can I tell AVD Manager where to find the directory?

Answer (score 1):

you can set the path for same sdk that you were using with Eclipse. Just follow these steps:

`File-> Project Structure->Android SDK location`.

Under Android SDK location, browse for you sdk that you are using with eclipse. Yoy may need to re-start Android Studio to take effect! i m using A.S 0.8.6!

Answer (score 1):

Even I had faced the same problem. `Tools -> AVD Manager -> Create Virtual Device` just adds the Virtual device. Underlying SDK (=~ Android OS selected while creating the Virtual device) should be separately installed.SDK can be installed from `Tools -> SDK Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio looks for different directories than Eclipse. From Android Studio, run the SDK Manager and verify that marks API 16 as installed. If not just install it and that should work

Comment: But that would be duplicate code. Isn't there a way to set the path? :(